# Reloading torrc without loosing flags

Tags: configuration, relays, flags, hsdir

Everytime I edit some parameters in my torrc file and then send a "pkill -sighup tor" to reload the configuration, I loose my HSDir-Flag and my uptime. Is it possible to reload the torrc without the mentioned points?

Just for your information the relay is hosted on a virtual server, with an estimated Traffic of about 6TB per Month and is running for about 18 days.

At the moment it has the following flags: Fast, Guard, HSDir, Running, Stable, V2Dir, Valid (bw=7020).

Kind regards

Comment: Brief downtime shouldn't affect flags. What "parameters" are you editing? Infact SIGHUP doesn't even cause downtime. Are you changing it's ports? If yes, then no there's no way you can do that without being down.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's what I thought too. I'll adjusted the RelayBandwithRate several times and everytime I've done that I lost the HSDir Flag. It came back as the "new uptime" reached four days. After I send SIGHUP and check the uptime via Atlas it is reseted.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - if you even  reboot your server for 2-3 minutes - you won't loose your flags, checked it myself. Just doing it from time to time on my relay with zero problems at all. Second - using `kill -1 <tor-pid>` seems to work fine. But if you need really "on-flight" replace without any interruptions - use a control protocol to make the corresponding changes in your "running-config", ciscoly-speaking :)

Comment: i have tried this hsflag dissapears after brief reboot whiting 2min